# (The) x of y. When is THE not needed?

Tags: definite-article

I thought THE is always needed in “the x of y”, but consider

peace of mind(e.g. My parents found it necessary for peace of mind.)

vexation of spirit (e.g. Better is one handful of rest than two handfuls of toil and vexation of spirit.)

Are these only exceptions? Any more exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you thought that "x of y" always requires a definite article. The rule is exactly the same as for a single-word noun: if it's a specific thing then it requires an article; if it's a generic quality, then it takes no article.

So the exact same "x of y" phrase can require an article in some situations, but not in others, depending on context.  For example:

> **The cessation of hostilities** was broken by a spate of suicide bombings.

This refers to a *specific situation*, so it requires an article.

> **Cessation of hostilities** is often facilitated by a neutral arbiter.

This is a *general statement*, so it takes no article.

Comment: I enjoy (the) stimulation of intellect. I especially value (the) pursuit of education. Are THE needed here? I can’t tell if they are specific situations or general statements.

Comment: thanks for a little more explanation in advance.